# Implementing Bucket Sort and Counting Sort Without Using Dynamic Memory Allocation

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, counting-sort, bucket-sort

I was practicing on sorting algorithms in C++ and I should be implementing the algorithms without using vectors. So the unsorted array size can be decided on the beginning `#define ARR_SIZE 25` and the elements are selected from uniformly distributed randoms.

```
void Sorters::InitializeArray()
{
for (int i = 0; i < ARR_SIZE; i++) {
    arr[i] = uniformRandom.RandomlyDistribute(LOWER_ARRAY_LIMIT, UPPER_ARRAY_LIMIT);
    }
}
```

Lower bound of the random is `#define LOWER_ARRAY_LIMIT 0` and upper bound is `#define UPPER_ARRAY_LIMIT 200`. I implemented a Bubble Sort, which is

```
void Sorters::BubbleSort(int arr[], int arraySize)
{
for (int k = 0; k < arraySize; k++)
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize - k - 1; i++)
        if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1]) {
            temporaryVal = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
            arr[i + 1] = temporaryVal;
        }
}
```

However, I have troubles with Bucket Sort and Counting Sort. How may I implement them ? In Bucket Sort, how will I decide each bucket size since it is not dynamic? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Bucket-sort:

You can do bucket-sort in-place, so there's no need to allocate additional space. Simply do a bucket-sort based on the binary representation. Here's the pseudo-code:

```
bucket_sort_int(arr, lower, upper, bit):
    if bit == -1:
        return
    
    l, u = lower, upper
    while l < u:
        if ~bitmask(bit) & arr[l]:
            l++
        else if bitmask(bit) & arr[u]:
            u--
        else:
            arr[l], arr[u] = arr[u], arr[l]
            l++
            u--

    bucket_sort_int(arr, lower, u, bit - 1)
    bucket_sort_int(arr, u + 1, upper, bit - 1)

bucket_sort(arr):
    bucket_sort_int(arr, 0, len(arr) - 1, sizeof(arr[0]) * 8 - 1)
```

Basically simply partition the array by the most significant bit, sort each of the partitions by the next most significant bit and recursively apply this until the entire array was sorted.

Counting sort:
The range of possible values in `arr` needs to be known beforehand anyways. So there's no need to use a dynamic array for that anyways. Simply use a global array of the predefined length and the standard algorithm and you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Excuse me but since I am a beginner, I need to ask how to use ~bitmask. Do you have any example small example for if I were about to use "~bitmask(bit)" and "bitmask(bit)". An additionally, in terms of the data type, what should be the type of bit? @Paul

Comment: @Metalian `bitmask(n)` is just the bitmask for bit `n`. So basically `bitmask(n) = 1 << n`. Also note that I've altered `bucket_sort` in the above code. `bit` is now `sizeof(arr[0]) * 8 - 1`.